# Basic HTML login for single user

Tags: html, forms, authentication

i have build a html login page for only one customer. I want it really simple, only email and password which i set and give to the visitor. for example ,
email:user@user.com
password: blabla

is that possible ?

```
<body class="login">
    <section>
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <form method="link" action="statistics.html">
            <input type="text" value="Email" />
            <input value="Password" type="password" />
            <button class="blue">Login</button>
        </form>
        <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    </section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Page load delay by Curtis Henson - http://curtishenson.com/articles/quick-tip-delay-page-loading-with-jquery/
$(function(){
    $('.login button').click(function(e){ 
        // Get the url of the link 
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  

        // Do some stuff 
        $(this).addClass("loading"); 

            // Stop doing stuff  
            // Wait 700ms before loading the url 
            setTimeout(function(){window.location = toLoad}, 10000);      

        // Don't let the link do its natural thing 
        e.preventDefault
    });

    $('input').each(function() {

       var default_value = this.value;

       $(this).focus(function(){
               if(this.value == default_value) {
                       this.value = '';
               }
       });

       $(this).blur(function(){
               if(this.value == '') {
                       this.value = default_value;
               }
       });

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's possible but your code is not capable to handle the process

Comment: what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code: You're assigning the value of `toLoad` to the `<button>`'s `href` attribute, which does not exist, and also **should not** exist, since the `href` attribute is not valid on a `<button>` tag. Also, I don't think `link` is a valid form method, you have to use either `GET` or `POST`.

Anyway, if you want to actually create a *functional* log in form, you're going to need PHP (and MySQL), it can't be done in pure JS+HTML. You can find tutorials for this all over the web, use your favourite search engine to find one that suits your needs.